# Can I exclude retweets and replies from specific users?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I connect twitter using Twitter4J. Here I am taking tweets using getUserTimeLine () but Retweets and Replies also appear.  How to exclude Retweets and Replies using getUserTimeLine () because I want to retrieve from a specific user ?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Twitter twitter1 = tf.getInstance();
List<Status> tweet;

System.out.print("Username : ");
String user = input.nextLine();

tweet = twitter1.getUserTimeline(user);
System.out.println("Show Timeline @" + user);
for (Status status : tweet) {
   System.out.println("Tweet : " + status.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [twitter docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html), it is possible to 
exclude RTs and replies using the `exclude_replies` and `include_rts` optional options.
But these options seem to not be present in Twitter4J. (grepped the code and did not find them)

Comment: do you have any solution ?

Comment: You could either contribute to Twitter4J by adding these as options. Or filter the results. Or shunt part or all of Twitter4J to perform the call with the exact options you would like

Answer (score 0):

You can to try using isRetweet() method which will return you `true` if this status is retweet.  And getInReplyToStatusId() method will return you value >0 if this status is the response to some other tweet.
In Java 8 streams you can simply filter

```
tweet = tweet.stream().filter(status -> !status.isRetweet() && status.getInReplyToStatusId()==0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `tweet = twitter1.getUserTimeline(user).filter(status -> !status.isRetweet() && status.getInReplyToStatusId()==0)`. Like this ? I got error

Comment: if you want to make it in 1 line - yes. Or  you can do it in 2 statemnts. First - `getUserTimeline`, second - filter received tweets.

Comment: updated my answer a little bit, cause in the end of the stream it's necessary to call `collect()` method